# When I emulate Ionic App it throws TypeError: Can't call method on undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-emulator, ionic2

I'm working on a Ionic 2 beta( latest version ) project. 
The app runs on web-client without any errors.
But when I try to emulate I get a white screen ( The White Screen of Death ).
There are no error logged in `adb logcat`.

So tried to emulate the app with live reload. ( As mentioned [here](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app/) ).

When I execute the command  `ionic emulate android -l -c`

I get this error:

```
Error happened TypeError: Can't call method on  undefined
  at TypeError (native)
  at module.exports (D:\ionicApp\node_modules\core-js\modules\_defined.js:3:28)
  at createHTML (D:\ionicApp\node_modules\core-js\modules\_string-html.js:7:19)
  at bold (D:\ionicApp\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.string.bold.js:5:12)
  at cb (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:206:7)
  at done (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:167:19)
  at C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:40:16
  at C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:193:9
  at [object Object].Console.log (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\transports\console.js:127:3)
  at emit (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:186:17)
  at C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:157:13
  at _each (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:57:9)
  at Object.async.each (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:156:9)
  at [object Object].Logger.log (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:214:9)
  at [object Object].target.(anonymous function) [as info] (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\common.js:54:18)
  at Object.IonicTask.setupLiveReload (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\cordova.js:338:7)
  at C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\ionic\cordova.js:104:21
  at _fulfilled (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
  at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
  at C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:509:49
  at flush (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
  at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:456:9)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:385:13)
```

Have anyone faced this, what was your solution?
Reference: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/emulate-run-with-livereload-not-working/48330

Comment: I had some problems with emulate myself (on iphone), but I solved it by using the ``run`` keyword instead:  ``ionic run android``

Comment: @John I tried using `ionic run android` but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you add android to your platforms? ``ionic platform add android``

Comment: yes, i have added.

Comment: I did the setup freshly still i get `Installing cordova-plugin-statusbar
Installing ionic-plugin-keyboard
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\emulation\projectIonic2\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:/emulation/projectIonic2
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\emulation\projectIonic2\hooks\after_prepare\011_update_config.js D:/emulation/projectIonic2
Caught exception:
 TypeError: invalid data
  at Socket.write (net.js:617:11)
  at Socket.stream.write`

Comment: Anybody solved this?

Comment: @StephanKristyn It is working on the latest ionic 2 beta release :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I have done the following.

1. Upgrade / downgrade to Cordova version 6.0.0
2. Upgrade / downgrade to Ionic version 2.0.0-beta.25
3. ionic state reset
4. ionic platform remove android
5. ionic platform add android
6. ionic run android

It works as of today....

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latsets ionic 2 release. `npm install ionic@beta`